# How to make an electronic suction cup?

Tags: robotics

The [uArm](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/ufactory/uarm-put-a-miniature-industrial-robot-arm-on-your) is a robot arm with a suction cup (or gripper). I'd like to try to make **just the suction part** of it, and I'm wondering what components I'd need?

By the looks of it, I'd need a hobby vacuum pump, but these seem few and far between on UK components sites.

How would I power it? It looks like they're all 12v, and I believe Arduino gives you 5v?

Exact what components would I need? Do I need any shields?

Here's a short video of the suction cup I'd like to copy:

[image]

Comment: What do you need to grip (i.e. how heavy)?

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin Very light; one suction cup above and one below a thin plastic bag to pull it open (they're thin and tight together - this was the best way I could think of to open them).

Comment: You, of course, could open it with fire... :D If the plastic bag has a long area above the "zipper," you might be able to make some sort of hand contraption, which might work better.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin The bags don't have zips. Just one open edge and one sealed edge. They're not the easiest to open until you get the nack of it. Suction would definitely be better I think.

Comment: Before talking about the electronics parts you will need, you must know the characteristics of the pump you will use: voltage AND current.

Comment: @jfpoilpret The main components suppliers here are RS Components and Farnell. I'm looking for the cheapest pump they (or another UK supplier) offer which is compatible.

Comment: This kind of pump typically needs current between 500mA and 2A, depending on the model. The selection of a transistor will be based on the current you have to switch with the transistor. It's pretty straightforward to find out a trnasistor that matches current/voltage requirements.

Comment: You first need to determine the "strength" of the pump you'll need, based on the max weight of items you want to be able to grip. That will give you a list of pumps and associated motors, with the power they need. Power and Voltage will give you the current. Current and Voltage will tell you which transistor you may use.

Comment: @jfpoilpret The weight is negligible, just thin A4 sized bags.

Comment: may I know What are the components called in that video called? What are the approximate specifications for this parts ?

Answer (score 4):

Just a note for those who wonder the same and are in need of a vacuum: In theory, you can use Venturi effect (or Bernoulli's Principle; it's basically the same) to create a vacuum. Or go buy an [Aspirator pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirator_(pump)). Since English is not my native language it's difficult for me to explain it in my own terms, but I'll try to give you a rough idea anyway. (Google it or feel free to answer with a better explanation).

First you need some flow of a fluid or gas (air from a compressor or water from a household outlet are fine). You pass that flow through left-to-right in a T-pipe (I'll call that the "flow pipe"). This will result in a weak vacuum in the orthogonal pipe (I'll call this the "vacuum pipe"), which you can connect to your suction cup.

The strength of the vacuum depends on the pressure in the "flow pipe". That means a higher velocity of your matter in the "flow pipe" is good (either a stronger compressor or smaller diameter of your flow pipe).

If I understand my physics book correctly, a higher density of the matter in your flow pipe will also produce a stronger vacuum. If you need a really strong vacuum, you could even use a water compressor, i.e. high pressure cleaner; but I suppose even a small air compressor will outperform a household water outlet (and you could toggle it from an Arduino with a relay board).

Since the air in the vacuum pipe expands more than many other materials, you could try to replace it with i.e. oil (be aware you'll pull out some of the air/replacement material at the intersection in aspirator!). This optimization is dangerous with a normal vacuum pump, since these usually break when sucking up fluids into their internals.

Also using an aspirator has the upside of not needing to buy a vacuum pump if you already own a compressor. On the other hand, that setup might be even louder (and possibly less efficient) than a dedicated vacuum pump.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches I can think of that would work decently. Either a.) suck air out of a "cup," turning off the pump when done. OR b.) have a valve where the arm pushes one part of the bag against the table to squeeze all the air out of it, and shutting a valve attached to the "cup." Then, to release, the valve could be opened. For the suction cup, I'd personally try making it out of a suction cup hanger like this:

[image]

*Source: [http://www.amazon.com/Set-Large-Suction-Hanger-Hook/dp/B00439SCZO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00439SCZO)*

The availability of these might vary by area, so I'm not sure how common these are in the UK. If you find one, make sure that it's pretty thick, with not that large of diameter so it's not too big to work with. I'd then remove the metal hook with pliers and drill a hole in the center. After that, you would need to superglue a tube through the center of the hole and seal it with some caulk.

Like I mentioned earlier, the two options are to a.) suck to grab and turn off pump to release or b.) have arm apply pressure to a flat surface and then shut a valve attached to the tube, creating negative pressure in the suction cup. Then, you could open the valve to balance the pressure and let the item go. I'd personally do the suction approach because, although it is louder and might use a little more electricity, it's a bit easier to build and execute and can grab in the air. I'm going to focus on that.

For the pump approach, build the suction cup (like I said above), attach the tube to one end of the motor with a hose clamp, leave the other hose terminal unconnected, and connect the pump (through a relay) to a 12V 1A+ power supply. You can do this by connecting the + pin of the pump to the "out" (or similar) pin of a relay breakout board, the "in" (or similar) of the relay to the power supply +, and the - of the pump to the power supply's - wire. This will make a circuit similar identical to a switch (the switch being the relay). To connect the relay to the Arduino you will have to connect the relay's logic signal to a pin on the Arduino and then you can just write `HIGH` or `LOW` to turn the pump on and off.

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention, you can use a transistor, too. Also, I illustrated the second method (hopefully it makes this clear).

[image]

Comment: So there's no way to have the pump on the same circuit without a relay? Your last paragraph is what's relevant to me. It's more the electronics I need help with. As for "squeeze all the air out", I'm not sure what you mean; there is no air whatsoever inside the bags. They're flat - only 1-2mm thick. Thanks for your answer, it's useful!

Comment: Actually you don't necessarily need a relay to command the pump, a transistor could be enough, depending on the current needed by the pump. The important thing is that you need a separate power supply (12V if this is what the pump needs) than Arduino 5V output.

Comment: @Danny You'll need a relay or transistor; the Arduino can only supply 4% of the current needed and 46% of the voltage needed. I haven't worked with transistors that much, so I can't advise you on that. As for the squeeze all the air out, I meant pushing the suction cup against a surface so the air *in* the suction cup flows out, through the tube. Then, when you would close the valve, it would try to expand, thus creating negative pressure between the bag and the cup. I'll try making a picture.

Comment: I am afraid the second method would require to exercise a high pressure first on the object to hold, that may need an engine even stronger than a pump! I think the vacuum-pump is more reliable here.

Comment: @jfpoil Yeah, it was a last minute kind of idea. If it works like I imagine it would, then it would need only slightly stronger arm motor.

Comment: You can control the 12v pump using any of the popular methods for controlling motors, Google "Arduino ULN2003" for many examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can't power things like pumps and motors with the power supply from an Arduino. It doesn't provide nearly enough current. It's meant for providing regulated 5V for low powered logic circuits, and nothing else.

What you can do is use a transistor as a switch to turn on and off the power from a suitable external power supply.

If you find a vacuum pump that runs on 12V, get a 12V power supply with enough current to drive the pump, and then use a [**MOSFET transistor**](https://www.adafruit.com/product/355) (example link) that will can handle enough current at 12V and can be controlled by a 5V signal to it's gate, and use that to switch the power on and off. Then you'd need a diode to protect the transistor against the reverse current you get from inductors like motors.